# Nextcloud first installation

Tags: nextcloud

I'm tring to install nextcloud on my linux server, but I receive the error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server was unable to complete your request.

If this happens again, please send the technical details below to the server administrator.

More details can be found in the server log.
```

On nextcloud.log file I've this error:

```
"message":{ 
  "Exception":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\TableNotFoundException",
  "Message":"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM \"oc_appconfig\"':\n\nSQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"oc_appconfig\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM \"oc_appconfig\"\n                      ^",
  "Code":0,
  "Trace":[ 
     { 
        "file":"\/www\/htdocs\/nextcloud\/3rdparty\/doctrine\/dbal\/lib\/Doctrine\/DBAL\/DBALException.php",
        "line":169,
        "function":"convertException",
        "class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver",
        "type":"->",
        "args":[ 
           "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM \"oc_appconfig\"':\n\nSQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"oc_appconfig\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM \"oc_appconfig\"\n                      ^",
           { 
              "errorInfo":[ 
                 "42P01",
                 7,
                 "ERROR:  relation \"oc_appconfig\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM \"oc_appconfig\"\n                      ^"
              ],
              "__class__":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException"
           }
        ]
     },
```

Why I've this error, if this is my first installation?

Answer (score 0):

you should provide **more information** about your installation.
example: os, web server, DB server, php version etc.

But for me it looks like something went/is wrong with the DB server. 
Is it accessible? If yes check if there is your DB.

Best regards
oBiE

Comment: problem solved. DB is ok, the problem was, that I've created config.php files and it is created automatically during installation.